# Ionic: run ionic app when the phone is reboot or turn on

Tags: cordova, ionic2

I am lookin for some way to make the ionic app run when the device/phone/android/ios is restarted or turned on.

This is for make run a background function in the app even when the app has been closed.

Thanks so much for help.

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://github.com/ToniKorin/cordova-plugin-autostart) plugin can help with android. Have a look.